# c++ vector elements access

Tags: c++, vector, types

I am trying to create a vector with a datatype I have already defined
 in a class

```
vector<MYdatatype> myVector;
```

but when I try to access the elements in the vector using a for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<myVector.size();i++)
```

I get an error message telling that the vector is out of range Debug assertion failed line 932!

THIS IS MY CODE

```
vector <Road_Segment> Unvisited;//the vector

for (i = 0; i<Unvisited.size(); i++)
{
    cur_node = Unvisited[0];//current node to visit

    find_node_neighbers(cur_node.end_station.ID, end, T_R);
```

when I try to comment this for loop I don't get that error message

any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you erasing some element from `Unvisited` inside the loop?

Comment: @Miki That wouldn't cause a problem, because it would adjust `Unvisited.size()` as well, so the loop would just exit sooner.

Comment: This should be run in a debugger. The assertion will pop and show you the call stack, where you can then see which index is wrong. Your loop has multiple places of potential failure, Which is the actual problem remains a mystery; we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
cur_node = Unvisited[0];
```

should really be:

```
cur_node = Unvisited[i];
```

Otherwise, it will just access the first element over and over.

But if you just need to perform an action on each element, you should use a foreach loop instead:

```
for (const Road_Segment& cur_node : Unvisited) {
  // I'm guessing "neighbers" is just a typo, but that's what was in the question
  find_node_neighbers(cur_node.end_station.ID, end, T_R);
}
```

This allows you to avoid any problems with indices and such. Or if you need to actually modify each element instead of just using it, simply remove the `const`:

```
for (Road_Segment& cur_node : Unvisited) {
  // do something that modifies cur_node
}
```

Comment: If you need to edit the `element` then you'd need to get rid of the `const`?

Comment: @Shaktal Yes, that's correct. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Should the for loop in question even being entered??

Comment: @RedRoboHood 
it also gives an exception on this
visited[visited.size() - 1] = Unvisited[visited.size()];

whats wrong with it?

p.s. visited and unvisited are both vectors

Comment: @SarahSaeed As with your [last attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229959/accessing-elements-in-a-vector-with-a-defined-datatype?noredirect=1#comment50459011_31229959), your question doesn't show the relevant context of the error you achieve. That accept is worth nothing.